# How to find and display information from json file with user input via batch command?

Tags: json, windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a json file (API.json) which looks like this:

```json
{"applist":{"apps":[{"appid":1234567,"name":"Test$: Number 1"},{"appid":7654321,"name":"Test- Number 2"},{"appid":7777777,"name":"Test & *(test)* Num. 3"}]}}
```

This is just the short version for testing.

I would like to know if it's possible to search for a "name" and view the related "appid" before that "name" via batch or any windows built-in commands.

E.g.

```bash
set /P name=Insert the name: 
rem (Part of the name which matches exactly with the name)
if %name%=Test$: echo
Name: Test$: Number 1
App ID: 1234567
rem (Part of the name which matches with more than 1 name)
if %name%=Number echo
Name: Test$: Number 1
App ID: 1234567
Name: Test- Number 2
App ID: 7654321
```

As it is obvious, `Test` or `Number` might, or might not be, included in the name.

I have tried converting this to object via PowerShell (convertto-json) but without any success. I Don't know if that would help.

Comment: If it actually is all on one line like that but it's actually longer, you're going to have an absolutely awful time trying to parse it in batch. Using `(Get-Content "API.json" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json)` in Powershell will make things infinitely easier for you.

Comment: Here we expect you to pose a programming problem in the question area, any answers belong in the answer area. I have therefore removed your answers, and ask that you submit them in the appropriate location instead.

Comment: @Compo: I believe that the `solutions` posted by OP are actually examples of failed attempts to solve the problem. OP is looking to fix one of these attempts.

Comment: @OP: Please format your code and data by selecting and pressing the `{}` button. Edit it until it is presented to all readers in the exact format that it appears to you. Layout can be critical in batch. Especially important **is the .json file a single line?** Please also explain your quest using realistic values for the data - don't attempt to generalise. For instance, "looking for name value `abc`" which occurs in your data.

Comment: Well I initially thought so @Magoo, but their second option provided an "acceptable" solution. Offering three different methods and asking for help would essentially be three different questions. In that case the question should be more focused, and would at least require OP action. There are also many examples of PowerShell and batch-file scripts on this site which parse and return items from a json, and there's no indication that those have been implemented here.

Comment: Post the actual JSON file content, complete with its encoding type, (e.g. UTF-8 BOM, UTF-16 LE, ANSI CodePage 1252, etc.), and the line ending styles used, (e.g. CR, LF, CRLF). This type of information is crucial for us to replicate your actual problem and formulate a focused solution. If the content itself does means your question exceeds question size limits, there are several good online sites, where you can include it to supplement your post by including the link.

Comment: Use a language that natively supports JSON format – batch isn't one of them…

Comment: The JSON file in that link @Parham.8, is clearly not displayed as a single line. Are you sure that it does not have multiple lines each ending with a LF character? Please open it in a half decent text/programming editor to confirm. Also you did not indicate the encoding type used in that file, as I had also requested. If you want a properly focused, and robust solution, please furnish us with that information, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "=Loading data, please wait." < NUL
call :loadData < API.json
echo/

:nextName
echo/
set "name="
set /P "name=Insert the name: "
if not defined name goto :EOF
set "$!name!" 2>NUL
goto nextName


:loadData

set /P "line="
set /P "next="
for /F "tokens=1* delims=}" %%a in ("!next!") do (
   set "line=!line:*[{={!%%a}"
   set "next=%%b"
)

set "EOF="
:nextLine

set /P "=." < NUL > CON
for %%n in (^"^
%Do not remove this line%
^") do for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!line:},{=}%%~n{!") do (
   for /F "tokens=2,4 delims={:,}" %%x in ("%%a") do (
      if "%%~y" neq "" set "$%%~y=%%~x"
   )
)

if defined EOF exit /B

set "line=!next:~1!"
set /P "next="
if "!next:~-3!" equ "]}}" (
   set "next=!next:~0,-3!"
   set "EOF=1"
)

for /F "tokens=1* delims=}" %%a in ("!next!") do (
   set "line=!line!%%a}"
   set "next=%%b"
)

goto nextLine
```

**IMPORTANT:**

- This program may fail for anyone of several causes
- This program may take too long
- This program fail in the fields that include an exclamation-mark. This can be fixed, but the program would take even longer...
- The "name" consults just match names that **start** with the given data

Please, report the result

**EDIT 2022/12/01:** *New faster method added*

This new Batch-JScript *hybrid* version should run much faster than the former pure-Batch one:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

echo Creating names.txt file, please wait
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < API.json > names.txt

:nextName
echo/
set /P "name=Insert the name: "
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF
findstr /I /L /C:"%name%" names.txt
goto nextName


@end


// JScript section

var data = WScript.Stdin.ReadAll(),
    elems = data.split("},{"),
    items;

for ( var i = 1; i < elems.length; i++ ) {
   items = elems[i].split(/[:,"]/);
   if ( items[3] ) {
      WScript.Stdout.WriteLine('"'+items[3]+'"='+items[1]);
   }
}
```

Copy this code to a .BAT file. This new version will search the given string in *any part* of the name.

Comment: I tried the code but it looks like my "." is stuck so it just echos "..." indefinitely. I have also tried running as admin but the results were the same.

Comment: Yes. The message that appears in the screen indicate: _"Loading data, **please wait**"_, and below **IMPORTANT** I said: "This program may take too long". Each "." indicate that 1 KB of data were read. If the file is 8,256,954 bytes long, then it takes 8,063 chunks, that is, 8,063 dots. If your screen is 80 characters wide, then the 8,063 dots will ocupy 100 lines...  I think this program could be split in 2 parts: in the first part the data would be extracted and the second part would serve to consult the data. In this way, the first part just needed to be generated once.

Comment: Ok. I added a new version that run much faster than the former one. In my computer it process your 8 MB file in less than 10 seconds... See the **edit** in my code.

Answer (score 0):

With [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) your task can be solved

**Strict version**: `NAME` must match exactly

```bash
NAME='Test & *(test)* Num. 3'
jq --arg name "$NAME" '.applist.apps[] | select(.name == $name) | .appid' <<< "$INPUT"
```

[Demo on jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/dHSFwq3GZFK)

**Output**

```
7777777
```

---

**Relaxed version 1**: case insensitive

```bash
NAME='test- number 2'
jq --arg name "$NAME" '.applist.apps[] | select((.name | ascii_upcase) == ($name | ascii_upcase)) | .appid' <<< "$INPUT"
```

[Demo on jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/IzSi9sq0Kfs)

**Output**

```
7654321
```

---

**Relaxed version 2**: case insensitive, `NAME` only partially matches

```bash
NAME='number'
jq --arg name "$NAME" '.applist.apps[] | select((.name | ascii_upcase) | contains($name | ascii_upcase)) | .appid' <<< "$INPUT"
```

[Demo on jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/ShCcYkYIZIf)

**Output**

```
1234567
7654321
```

Comment: I just installed jq and tried this command: `jq .applist[] API.json` 
which converts the format into propper json format and removes "applist".
If I use `jq .applist[] | .name'  API.json` I get this: '.name'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
If I use your command, I get this: 'NAME' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
'*' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. 
What am I doing wrong? I'm using windows cmd by the way.

Comment: Also using `jq --arg name "$NAME" '.applist.apps[] | select(.name == $name) | .appid' API.json` shows this: 'select' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: It seems to be a quoting problem, because the error message is not generated by jq, but by your environment. Take a close look at your quoting. Your first comment is missing an quotation mark. I use Linux and do not know the specifics of quoting in Windows. The syntax of jq is the same between Windows and Linux

Comment: For the second line I modified the quoting to make it work stand-alone: `jq ".applist.apps[] | .name,.appid" API.json` But for the first line I had no success. The error happens because NAME is considered as 'NAME' and is not recognized. So if anyone knows how to make jq work with this code plus user input, I would appreciate the answer. Thank you!

Comment: see it work on [jq play](https://jqplay.org/s/QN6CTxsJhTo)

Comment: `jq '"Test & *(test)* Num. 3" as $name | .applist.apps[] | select(.name == $name) | .name,.appid'` Works pretty well and fast on jqplay. Is it possible to make it less strict? Meaning to add case insensitive and also make it show IDs even when part of the name is written instead of the whole name.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. I added two more versions to my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. It works great now. I would definitely use it.

Comment: I did upvote your answer. but my reputation is not enough to count it. Please upvote my questions/answers if you find them helpful, so that I could upvote your answer.
Thank you.